# Page split where existing rows are moved to different page occurs only for updates and non-sequential inserts?

Tags: sql-server, page-splits

Suppose page is full, and an item is inserted in order, then that item will get added to the next page. There will never be page split such that some rows are placed on a page and some rows move to another page.

Where as if an update is performed such that an item needs to be placed somewhere in an already full page, then a page split happens where some rows are kept of this page and other rows are moved to a new page.

So a page split where **existing** rows are moved to different page occurs only for updates and non-sequential inserts?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Inserts also cause page splits because contiguous keys must be stored in the same page.

Comment: Hi @DanGuzman can you elaborate please. Would this happen for inserts on an sequential index?

Comment: @DanGuzman - Since its sequential, that means when page is full then new record will be added to new page. Why would existing records get moved?

Comment: @variable, consider a full page with keys 1 and 3. When key 2 is inserted, SQL Server will allocate a new page and split the existing one such that you end up with only key 1 in the existing page and keys 2 and 3 in the new page (or key 1 and 2 in the existing page and key 3 in the new page).

Comment: But this question is pertaining to sequential inserts only.

Comment: @DanGuzman When the page split happens, and key 1 ends up in the existing page and 2,3 in new page then does the max-size of the page1 end up being of size=1 or is there extra space inside page1(can it now hold a key which is 1.5)?

Comment: @ajaysinghnegi, there will be unused space inside of the page after the split. A subsequent insert of the adjacent key 1.5 key will be inserted into the same page unless the size of the new row is too large to fit in the page.

Comment: @DanGuzman So, it's not actually a "page-split" but rather the data split into existing and new page, right? The word is confusing :)

Comment: @ajaysinghnegi, yea, the terminology is confusing for those new to SQL Server.

Answer (score 4):

For a SQL Server rowstore index, there are two kinds of page splits.  Others have mentioned, as has the poster of the question, that updates or inserts in the interior of the logical order of the index can lead to an interior page split due to exceeding the limit of the 8k page. That's one type of page split.

The second type of page split for a rowstore index occurs at the logical end of the index. As the last 8k page in index logical order reaches it's fullest state and the index spills into the next page - that is a page split. It is not as intensive of an operation as the split of a page from the interior of the index.  And while an interior page split will usually leave the rowstore index with less logical contiguity and higher reported index fragmentation (as reported by sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats), a page split at the end of the index logical order will not do so(usually although some conditions of limited unallocated extents in the database file(s) may occasionally lead to this).

Having established that both INSERT and UPDATE can lead to page splits in rowstore indexes, what about DELETE?

Yes, even DELETE can lead to rowstore index page splits.  Interior page splits (the more intensive, less desirable kind) or a page split at the logical end of the index.

For an outstanding explanation of how row versioning + DELETE can result in page splits, I recommend the blog post referenced below from Paul White. Basically, when row versioning is introduced to a database page that previously did not have to accomodate it, the 14 byte versioning info per row can result in a page split.

Deletes that Split Pages and Forwarded Ghosts
2012 August 31
https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/08/deletes-that-split-pages-and-forwarded-ghosts.html

Comment: Can INSERT on an sequential index value cause Page split where existing rows are moved to different page?

Comment: That's a good question :-) I'm inclined to believe the answer is yes but i'll have to do some research and thinking :-)

Comment: Since its sequential, that means when page is full then new record will be added to new page. Why would existing records get moved?

Comment: i can't think of a scenario with an uncompressed rowstore index - or with a row-compressed rowstore index - where inserts following the order of a sequential key would result in relocating rows that were already in that database page.  But in the case of page compression, I think it may be possible. Because most if not all compression algorithms  have edge cases where the end result is larger than previously. At any rate, it would I believe be a rare outlier.

Answer (score 1):

If the row to be inserted has a key value greater than any on the target page then a page split occurs, but no rows are migrated to the new page.  The new page is allocated, the forward and reverse page pointers are updated and the new row is written to the new page.

Note that this behavior happens whether the target page is at the end of the index or somewhere in the middle.  This is important because NEWSEQUENTIALID() and compound keys get efficient middle-of-index inserts.

See [Good Page Splits and Sequential GUID Key Generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dbrowne/good-page-splits-and-sequential-guid-key-generation) for details about the inserting sequential values into the middle of an index.

Answer (score 0):

You assume that rows will always be inserted in order. While this is typically the case, as it's more common to see sequential keys used instead of non-sequential, it's still not uncommon to see a non-sequential GUID used instead.

Using a GUID, inserts would occur randomly across all of your pages. Therefor, future inserts may target space between two rows in an already full page. To make room for this new row, a page split would need to happen.

Thus, a page split can happen for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operations.